# Why the past tense? And how can I understand these 'would's and 'could's?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

> How could a humble tortoise beat the legendary Greek hero Achilles in a race? The Greek philosopher Zeno liked a challenge and came up with this paradox. First, the tortoise is given a slight head start. Anyone fancying a flutter **would** still rush to put their money on Achilles. But Zeno **pointed** out that, to overtake him, Achilles **would** first have to cover the distance to the point where the tortoise **began**. In that time the tortoise **would** have moved – so Achilles **would** have to cover that distance, giving the tortoise time to amble forwards a bit more. Logically this **would** carry on forever. However small the gap between them, the tortoise **would** still be able to move forwards while Achilles **was** catching up. Meaning that Achilles **could** never overtake.
>   <sub>Source: [60-Second Adventures in Thought](http://media-podcast.open.ac.uk/feeds/thoughtexperiments-01/transcript/60second01_01691_16693.pdf) (Open University). ([YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=skM37PcZmWE))</sub>

My question: I don't understand the tense of the bold verbs. When telling a story, we normally use present tense, but why the author use almost all the past forms?

Comment: Stories are past actions. Narrative tenses are used for story-telling. This story shows some of the narrative tenses, other include the *past continuous, perfect* & *perfect continuous.*

Comment: It depends what **kind of story** you are telling. If you are **making up** a story or reporting a story **as it happens**, you would use the **present tense**, if your story takes place 10 years time, you might use the **future tense**.  This story happens in the past (ancient Greece) and so uses the **past tense**

Comment: You can also tell a story that happened in the past using the present tense  (see [Historical Present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present)).

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to explain this, but it's hard to spell out the rules (for English modal verbs) precisely. I'd like to give you a little tip to deal with them:

In English, there are two main time domains (non-past and past), and thus there are two verb forms for them: the present form and the past form. (Let's not discuss the past participles for now.)

The main uses of the past form are a) for things that happened in the past, and b) for [things that didn't or don't actually happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis_mood) (such as our "hypothetical race" in this video).

---

The following is disclosed-captions™ (mainly for the times and tenses) for the above video clip:

> *How **could** a humble tortoise beat the legendary Greek hero Achilles in a race?*
>   This is a typical use of *could*. It's commonly used as an opening question of presentation, a talk, a speech, and such. This one invites the listener to take it as a [thought experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_experiment).
>
> *The Greek philosopher Zeno **liked** the challenge and came up with this paradox.*
>   There is nothing special here. [Zeno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno_of_Elea) lived 490 BC - 430 BC. At the time you listen to the video, all Zeno's actions happened in the past, so we use a past tense: the simple past.
>
> *First, the tortoise **is** given a slight head start.*
>   Now the narrator is telling us about a "rule" of the race (which is our thought experiment). If he used the simple past instead of the present simple, it would be from Zeno's perspective, but he simply uses the present simple which makes it easier for us to get along with what he's telling. It's more vivid this way, as if it were really happening in front of us. (And the video reinforces this effect!)
>
> *Anyone fancying a flutter **would** still rush to put their money on Achilles.*
>   This *would* is used because it's hypothetical. If the race were about to happen now, those who wanted to make a bet would bet on Achilles. They would think Achilles would win the race.
>
> *But Zeno **pointed** out that, to overtake him, Achilles **would** first have to cover the distance to the point where the tortoise **began**.*
>   The narrator tells us that Zeno pointed that out (in the past), that if there was such a (hypothetical) race, Achilles *would* (hypothetical) have to do that, he would have to run to the point where the tortoise *began* (hypothetical). This hypothetical race is timeless. In other words, whenever we had such a race, if we could arrange such as a race, Achilles would have to do that, every time.
>
> *In that time the tortoise **would have moved** – so Achilles **would** have to cover that distance, giving the tortoise time to amble forwards a bit more.*
>   We are still in the hypothetical race here, but notice the use of *would have moved*. It's not just *would move*. It's *would have moved*. The use of *would have moved* tells us that if that hypothetical race is a real one, the tortoise will (logically) have already moved. It has already moved. And because the tortoise has already moved, Achilles can do nothing better than to cover that distance. So in our hypothetical race, he *would* have to cover that distance.
>
> *Logically this **would** carry on forever.*
>   Logically, our hypothetical race would keep going on and on, forever!
>
> *However small the gap between them, the tortoise **would** still be able to move forwards while Achilles **was** catching up, meaning that Achilles **could** never overtake.*
>   The use of the past forms in *would still be able to*, *was catching up*, and *could never overtake* is only because the race is hypothetical.